# Rotation in Unity2D

Tags: c#, android, unity3d-2dtools

Is it possible to move a game object from one side of the screen to the other, but have it rotating in a circle at the same time??

For example, I'm using this code to move the object:

```
Vector3 carPos = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, Random.Range (7.09f, -6.63f), transform.position.z);
```

How can I get the object to rotate 360 degrees on its axis over say 2 seconds?? I tried playing around with z positions but it makes move in a circle only and not across the screen.

Comment: Try around `transform.Rotate(0, 0, 10)`; combined with simple translation. To calculate the angle that will fit there nicely you'll have to math up (will revolve around `animTime` `distance` and `Pi`)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to Unity, I'd appreciate it if you explained what you mean with the translation??

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Animation in unity to rotate your object, you can configure the time and velocity

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation

Comment: This link takes me to a very broad topic in animation. I only have basic knowledge in Unity as I've just moved over from Xcode. Any chance of some code??

Comment: in the link you can see some examples, the animator is a visual tool, so i cant give you a part of code

Answer (score 0):

Use transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(A, B,...) to move the object from Point A to point B. At the same time (and i'm not sure if i understand you correct) use transform.Rotate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltatime) to rotate your Object around z. Put both in the Update Loop.